# Place content (or ads) between HTML that is returned from a php server?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, laravel

I am using laravel, vuejs.

Its a simple question. But i need to know if it works before creating it. So what i am currently doing is

- I have a WYSIWYG editor. I am saving the content from it into a html file and i am storing the location to that html file as a reference in my database
- When the user requests a page, I am retrieving that html file and send the content to the page and place the content in the page.

Now to the question, I need to place adsense code between some contents in the html piece(returned from the server). The html is a whole content returned from the php server. Right?

So how can i place adsense code between each paragraph or so after the content is returned from server?

Comment: You could add it using php, splitting up the datastring and inserting additional code, or using js and sth like document.getElementsByClassName and insertAfterElement

Comment: 1: why not just store the HTML in the database? 2: do you really want to place an advert after *every* paragraph?!

Comment: @CD001 Because inserting and retrieving large text from database makes the application slow. So i think its best to store it in a html file.

Comment: If your database is properly designed it should be as quick as retrieving data from the filesystem (quicker in some instances depending on OS level caching and complexity of the filesystem).

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider storing content in a DB. But if you really need to store HTML in files for some reason, you can use HTML tags like `!adsense!` in your editor. Then just read HTML from a file and use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) or similar function to replace this tag with actual ad code.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

As Alexey said, you may consider storing the content on the DB.
Also, you could consider actually using markdown instead of HTML, you could still use the WYSIWYG, but is easier to pre process it and easy to convert to HTML.

That being said, I second that the best option is to either use "key" to be replaced after, but that would mean giving the control to the person who edits if he wants to add the ad or not.

I would actually think you should pre process that HTML, there are some libraries to pre process it or you could use a regular expression, but, bottom line, you read the HTML before you output it, and find out what is a paragraph (depends on how your WYSIWYG is formatting things, this is why I prefer markdown), for example, you could split it in paragraphs based on the P tags or something like that, and then re assemble that, but adding the ad every X paragraphs, that way you can control how and when you put the ad, instead of the person who edits it.

To pre process the HTML you could use something like one of the following options:

- Symphony DOM Crawler (recomended): http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html
- PHP DOM Functions: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php
- A PHP HTML Parser Library: https://github.com/paquettg/php-html-parser

Or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I would give it a try.